# CakePHP Pagination with Webservice

Tags: web-services, cakephp, pagination

I am invoking a web service and get data. The result has "TotalPages", "TotalResults" information.

Based on this, I need to generate a paging mechanism using cakephp.

Please share some code snippet or advise me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The [Pagination Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) will make displaying the paginated data a lot easier for you. However, it operates on the assumption that you are using a Cake Model. Luckily, you can create a Datasource (the manual is [empty](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html), but the [API documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-DataSource.html) and [searching Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp+datasources) will teach you more) and a Model to use your Datasource and you should be in business.

The [Yahoo BOSS](http://www.neilcrookes.com/2009/01/30/cakephp-site-search-with-yahoo-boss/) and [RSS Feed](http://blog.loadsys.com/2009/06/19/cakephp-rss-feed-datasource/) Datasources should be useful examples.